# Add additional onClick() to Navigation Control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox offers [NavigationControls](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#navigationcontrol). A Compass (and others) come for free when using Mapbox. I can use the Compass to tilt the around the x and y Axis. When I tilted the map and click on the compass, the tilting is reverted. Is there a way to put an additional `onClick()` function on the compass?

I want to add this functionality

```
this.map.flyTo({
  center: ...
  zoom: 24
});
```

Currently I am having an extra Button for this which I add manually to the map. But I want to functionality to be included when clicking on the compass. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you just add an event listener with .on? So for example map.on('click', yourFunction);

Comment: @bdbdbd than this function is executed every time a user clicks on the map, not the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mousedown event to avoid overwriting the click event.

```
document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-ctrl-compass').addEventListener('mousedown', () =>{
   //your code
  })
```

If you're using React, to let time for the querySelector to find the element, use a setTimeout

```
setTimeout(
 () =>
  document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-ctrl-compass')
  .addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
   //your code
   }),
   500,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just add another click listener on the compass button.

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
map.on("load", () => {
  document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-ctrl-compass').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    console.log('click');
    map.flyTo({
      center: [77.1025, 28.7041],
      zoom: 24,
      pitch: 0,
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: That overwrites the original function, resetting it to north and removing the tilting. I want to keep that function too.